# Set Language on speech recognition plugin

Tags: speech-recognition

How can i change the default Language in SpeechRecognitionPlugin :

https://github.com/macdonst/SpeechRecognitionPlugin

I didn't find any documentation on it.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find it : `recognition.lang = "es-ES";`

Comment: Find it by myself ... There is no correct documentation :/